# CakePHP Missing Plugin exception after deletion

Tags: php, cakephp, plugins, cakephp-2.0

I just deleted the Media Plugin and edited my bootstrap.php.  I'm now getting a Missing plugin exception.  Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're probably still referring to the plugin somewhere in your application, for example by trying to use a `Helper` or a `Model` that uses the plugin notation;

- Clear the cache of your application, by removing the **content** of the `app/tmp/cache/models` and `app/tmp/cache/persistent/` directories
- Look for helpers, components, behaviors and models that use the plugin, for example:

Helpers and models in a controller:

```
 public $helpers = array(
    'Media.Somehelper',
 );

 public $uses = array(
    'Media.Somemodel'
 );
```

Or in a model;

```
public $actsAs => array(
    'Media.Somebehavior',
);
```

Comment: My mistake, I was referencing it in an actsAs variable within one of my models, thanks again!

Comment: Glad I could help, I'll add an 'actsAs' example to my answer as well, just for completeness